# Using AppleCare before it runs out

Tags: apple-watch, applecare

I have a first generation Apple Watch Sport with some minor cosmetic imperfections and scratches after two years of use, with Apple Care+.
The support runs out soon, and I was wondering what use it the cover has.

Specifically: If I were to 'accidentally' 'drop' my Watch, could I claim that on Apple Care and get a brand new one, or at least screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hardware accidental damage coverage is only good for 2 incidents over the life of the AppleCare+.  Each incident is subject to a US$69 service fee + tax.

You don't have to accidentally drop your Watch, you can just tell them that the glass was accidentally damaged during normal use and you want to make a claim (assuming you haven't already made at least 2 damage claims so far).  You'll be charged a service fee and they'll either repair the glass or provide you with a refurb Sport watch.

There should be no need for moral quandaries while doing this.  You bought the coverage to help you for this very purpose.

Answer (score 3):

I was in an Apple Store before XMAS to buy an Apple Watch and the salesman sold me on Apple Care + saying I would be covered in the event of damaging the glass. So yes you could do that, but only you would know if you can live with doing so.

Comment: Too true, the moral side is something to think about. But is it missuse, if you paid for the service, and will pay the service fee?

Comment: About 10yrs ago I got a brand new top of the range MacBook Pro under my home contents insurance. It was all legitimate as my original laptop was damaged while camping. But I still felt guilty for ages because the old laptop was an old PowerBook G4. I got over it and have been tempted many times to drop my current laptop but I always chicken out. It's a decision for you.

Comment: @Little.Eden I had a very similar experience, except I was running an Internet Cafe at a festival (not camping) when my PowerBook G4 died due to the extreme heat. The insurance repairer deemed it uneconomical to repair and I got a brand new top model MacBook Pro! I can tell you though I didn't feel at all guilty about it! :) That said, I agree that there is a moral side to this and wouldn't condone it.

Answer (score 3):

When you bought Apple Care+ with your Apple Watch, you have an 2 year extended warranty. Regarding the hardware, the coverage is for the following:
1. Your Apple Watch
2. The battery (if below 80% charging of original capacity)
3. Accessories

Within the 2 years that you have Apple Care, it is possible to replace your Apple Watch for $69 (Apple Watch/ Apple Watch Nike+) or $79 (Apple Watch Edition/Hermes)

Keep in mind that if you send in your Apple Watch for repairs, it is possible that you will get a brand new one, but it's more likely that you will get a refurbished device.

A refurbished device has a brand new case, screen and battery. Other components could be used before in another Apple Watch. A refurbished device does undergo additional quality checks. (I'm not 100% sure if this is true for Apple Watch, but this is the case for a refurbished iPhone).

Service fees may vary for your country. [See Apple Care+ for Apple Watch support page (US)](https://www.apple.com/support/products/watch.html)